# Retrieve FaceBook user's friends profile pictures with Graph API v2.3

Tags: facebook, permissions, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I am in the prototype and research stage of an app that would create a quiz about a FaceBook user's friends. The gist is that each question would ask the user to match the profile picture of her Facebook friend with the name of the Facebook user that picture belongs to.

As I read the v2.3 [Facebook API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3), specifically the section about the `user_friends` permission,  it appears that any app I make will only be able to get the user's friends' info if the friend has also installed and authorized my app.

If this is indeed the case, I won't even attempt the app as it's unlikely to be any fun if the content is limited to the set of friends who have installed the app.

Is there any other way to get the user's friends info while staying within the bounds of the Facebook Developers Terms of Service AND without requiring that the user's friend has installed and authorized my app?

Comment: I just ran into this question while searching for ways to get a facebook users friend list. Would like to know, did you build the app that you are talking about.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is indeed the case, you can only get access to friends who authorized your App with `user_friends` too. There is no other way since you don´t want to "invite friends to a canvas game" or "tag friends".

Check out the answer in this thread for more information: [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u)